# Homotopy equivalence between Möbius strip and cylinder

Tags: general-topology

Does anybody know a concrete homotopy equivalence $f:X \to Y$, where $X$ is the Möbius strip and $Y$ is the cylinder $S^1\times I$?
I do know that they are homotopy equivalent since both of them deformation retract onto $S^1$, but that is not what I am looking for.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, you already know they are both homotopic to $S^1$, homotopy is transitive...

Answer (score 2):

A deformation retract $F:X\times I\rightarrow X$ of $X$ onto $A\subset X$ induces a homotopy equivalence by taking $F(-,1):X\rightarrow A$ and the inclusion $\iota:A\rightarrow X$. You can now take the composition of the homotopy equivalences $M\rightarrow S^1\rightarrow S^1\times I$.